# Parsing json from the BigCommerce API output with python

Tags: python, json, api, bigcommerce

This is a simplified output I get from the BigCommerce API:

```
[<Orders at 0x2fc08605d4c0, {'id': 100, 'customer_id': 1}>,  
 <Orders at 0x2fcc40e14e60, {'id': 101, 'customer_id': 1}>]
```

I just can't seem to work out a simple efficient way to access the dicts inside the list.  I could get a list of hundreds of these with at least a hundred keys and values inside so I am trying to access the values quick and easily.  Any ideas?

I'm just trying to find the best way to add them to a database.

Comment: DidSquids, have you tried deserializing the API response? After deserializing the json using loads() you should be able to work with the data as a Python dictionary. 

I found this article that may prove useful in this process:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deserialize-json-to-object-in-python/

I also found this article that goes into depth on how to iterate through dictionaries: 
https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/

Comment: Thank you very much @HeatherBarr I will look into deserialising the response.   Appreciate the help.